# replace item in @ARGV in perl

Tags: perl, argv

I have a perl script that accepts a long option like `--pager='less -R'` and I want to shorten it to -p only.  It's a quick hack, I don't know perl and I'm assuming the most direct way is to search and replace -p in the ARGV array (or whatever it's called in perl) with --pager='less -R' before it starts to process the command line arguments.

Comment: Why not search the code for "pager" and try what happens if you change it to "p"?  (Please keep a copy of the original script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
s/^-p$/--pager/ for @ARGV;
```

as a quick hack. Just do not enter `-p` as a value to any option. Also, always use a space after `-p`.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you definitely need [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt%3a%3aLong), part of the core Perl distribution.

Although it isn't a *quick hack*, it is in my opinion the *proper* way to handle arguments. Read the documentation, you will see how fast you can handle such things.

Comment: I understand, someone else, however, could find the module interesting.

Comment: Some thoughts on why you should always use Getopt::Long. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=687283. If you have the time, you should read tchrist's original message from p5p too.

Comment: and actually Getopt::Long has been core since Perl 5 was released. No need for a CPAN install.

Answer (score 3):

Why reinvent the wheel, especially if you're not interested in 'proper' Perl programming?

Would it hurt to add a [couple of extra lines](https://metacpan.org/modules/Getopt%3a%3aLong)?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $pager = 'default value';
GetOptions( 'pager=s' => \$pager ) or die "Could not load options\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the option is given as `--pager="less -R"`, then I suspect that the script is using [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).  Change the corresponding variable accordingly.

Comment: it isn't a matter of changing pager to p it's a matter of substituting the literal '-p' for '--pager="less -R"'